# Product tab changing issue in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2

I have tabs on product page like **Details**, **Reviews** etc. so how can I change the label of this default tabs in Magento 2. I use Magento 2.2.

How can I archive this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In
>   app/design/frontend/[Package]/[Yourtheme]/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml:

For Details tab to Description :-

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">                
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.description">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Description</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

For more information :-

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">                
      <referenceBlock name="product.attributes">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Product Attributes</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

and add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">                
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.description">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Custom Description</argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
            <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Custom Review</argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```